# show tables from different sql tables that unrelated

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i want to show 2 tables that contain diffent information in a single codeigniter view page

heres the code on model.php (they are in the same class

```
> public function showPlants(){
> return $this->db->get('plantsdata');
> }
> 
> public function showAnimals(){
> return $this->db->get('animalsdata');
> }
```

the code on controller.php

```
> public function plantsandanimals() {
> $data = [
> 'finaldata'=>$this->db->showPlants()->result()
> ];
> $data = [
> 'finaldata'=>$this->db->showAnimals()->result()
> ];
> $this->load->view('viewplantsandanimal',$data);
> }
```

and then the viewplantsandanimals.php

```
<table>
<?php foreach ($finaldata as $here) { ?>
<tr>
<td> <?= $here->animalsname
</td>
<?php }; ?>
<tr>
</table>


<table>
<?php foreach ($finaldata as $here) { ?>
<tr>
<td> <?= $here->plantsname
</td>
<?php }; ?>
<tr>
</table>
```

that so i can have two tables to show animals and plants. but every tutorial on google either

1. join the table
2. make the plants table looping until have 9 data (animals has 9 records and plants has 3)

Comment: Simply merge the result of both queries or assign them to separate keys in the `$data` array. If you don't know the basics, getting your hands dirty on a framework directly is bad start!

Comment: 1. this is a homework
2. i dont want to learn framework either
3. i still dont understand what you mean by that because that is literally what i did

Comment: `<?= $here->animalsname` <- you don't close the PHP tag on this. `<?= $here->plantsname` <- you don't close the PHP tag on this. You have a dangling `<tr>` that is missing a closing `</tr>` tag.

Comment: okaaayy einstein

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close and I'm hoping I'm not helping you cheat !! But you can include different names in the array and then call the different names on the view page. Something like this:

```
public function plantsandanimals() {

    $data = [
        'plants'=>$this->db->showPlants()->result(),
        'animals'=>$this->db->showAnimals()->result()
    ];

    $this->load->view('viewplantsandanimal',$data);
}

foreach ($plants as $here) OR foreach ($animals as $here)
```